# TypeError: an integer is required (got type datetime.datetime) when trying to convert a datetime object within a dictionary to a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, dictionary

So I'm working in Python 3.7.4 with user-inputted dates, that are stored by another program in a variables in a dictionary format.  These can potentially be any date in the immediate past.  For instance November 6th 2019 looks like this:

```
{'Select start date': datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 6, 0, 0)}
```

I don't care about the item label, but I'd like to convert this dictionary date to the format 06 Nov 2019 (which I know is `strftime('%d %b %Y')`) but I'm not sure how to make it understand that the above is a datetime object and do a conversion on it when it's actually a dictionary object, and without throwing up errors.

I've read a lot on here about this but almost all questions here just look at either today's date (so `datetime.datetime.now()` is used), or a specific date, rather than a user-inputted date that could vary, and lives inside a dictionary.  I've already seen plenty of stuff like this:

```
import datetime
d = datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 06, 0, 0, 0, 000000)
d.strftime("%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S %z")
```

...but it doesn't seem to apply in exactly this case.  Commands like `strftime` and `strptime` don't seem to work because of the dictionary format, and I can't use static examples like the above because the actual date that I want to convert won't always be the same.  How can I make this work without going some crazy long way using string manipulation?  I feel like there's a really easy solution to this that I'm missing.

Code example (that doesn't work):

```
import datetime

dic = {'Select start date': datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 7, 0, 0)}

for key, value in dic.items():
     d = datetime.datetime(value)
     d.strftime("%d %b %Y")
```

Produces the error:

```
TypeError: an integer is required (got type datetime.datetime)
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  A datetime instance is better than a string in every way, you should only convert to string if you need to serialize it.

Comment: I don’t understand why the `strftime()` method you mentioned wouldn’t work. Can you expand on that a bit more? I also want to confirm that when you say _the actual date will change_, you’re referring to just the date and not the format.

Comment: I'm doing this because another program (that I don't control) wants the date in that particular format.  Yes I'm talking about the actual date changing i.e Nov 6th is just an example, but I do want to change the format of that date from datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 6, 0, 0) to Nov 6th 2019. strftime() doesn't seem to like it that the date is within a dictionary, trying to pull it out generates errors where an integer is expected, but I don't actually want an integer.

Comment: Edited to clarify the question a bit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I see now what is happening. The line `d = datetime.datetime(value)` is the issue, you are passing a datetime object to the `datetime.datetime()` method which is why you get the valueError. This is unnecessary because you are already getting a datetime object out of your dictionary, so there is no reason to construct a new one. Here's the fixed code:

```
import datetime

dic = {'Select start date': datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 7, 0, 0)}

for key, datetime_obj in dic.items():
     datetime_str = datetime_obj.strftime("%d %b %Y")
     print(datetime_str)
```

An easy way to debug this is to use `type()`. So for example:

```
for key, value in dic.items():
    print(type(value))
```

will give you `<class`datetime.datetime`>`. Looking up the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) for datetime.datetime() will tell you that this method only accepts integers.